InnoDB LRU buffer issues on MariaDB 10.5
I'm in the process of upgrading all of our replicas from MariaDB 10.3 to 10.5.  One of our rotations keeps running out of RAM.  These hosts all have 128GB of RAM (for a ~350GB database).  Buffer pool is set to 95GB.
The performance_schema (if I'm understanding it right) shows buf0lru for our RO user using up ~11GB.  This is after about 2 weeks of uptime.  It starts low and then grows indefinitely.
MariaDB [performance_schema]> select USER, EVENT_NAME, CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED USED_BYTES, CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED/1024/1024/1024 USED_GB from memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name  where CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED != 0 order by  CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED desc limit 5;
+--------------+----------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| USER         | EVENT_NAME                 | USED_BYTES   | USED_GB   |
+--------------+----------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| NULL         | memory/innodb/buf_buf_pool | 102005473280 | 95.000000 |
| ro-user      | memory/innodb/buf0lru      |  12190591608 | 11.353373 |
| NULL         | memory/innodb/buf0lru      |   9725319472 |  9.057410 |
| NULL         | memory/innodb/hash0hash    |   3077514736 |  2.866159 |
| NULL         | memory/innodb/os0event     |   1569318016 |  1.461541 |
+--------------+----------------------------+--------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.021 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'innodb_buffer%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 1              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 102005473280   |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'innodb_flush%';
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                  | Value    |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout    | 1        |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 2        |
| innodb_flush_method            | O_DIRECT |
| innodb_flush_neighbors         | 1        |
| innodb_flush_sync              | ON       |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops      | 30       |
+--------------------------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%lru%';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| innodb_lru_flush_size | 32    |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth | 1536  |
+-----------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)


Settings are the generally the same for all of our hosts, but this is the only rotation I've noticed this issue in.  A bit of additional info is these hosts do handle a fair amount of slower queries.
Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance!
